# PHP: Show 3 td's of data per table row

Tags: php

I am wanting to use 8 images from my database and load them into a HTML Table. I would like to display 4 images per table row, but however when i run my code below, i seem to get all images in one table row. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

```
$count = $get->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0)
        {
            echo '<table id="" class="uiGrid _51mz _1m6c" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';

            $i = 0;

            while ($r = $get->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {   
                $globals = new \Libraries\Helpers\Views\Globals;

                if ($i == 0)
                {
                    echo '<tr class="_51mx">';
                }

                echo '
                    <td class="_51m-">
                        <a href="/e/a/'.$r->data_id.'">
                            <div class="uiScaledImageContainer _f-u2" style="width:74px;height:74px;">
                                <img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://gstatic.acfee.org/akamaihd/i/'.$globals->data_image_name($r->data_id).'">
                                <div class="_3s6x">
                                    <div class="_50f3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                     ';

                if ($i > 4)
                {
                    $i = 0;
                    echo '</tr>';
                };

                $i++;

                echo '
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#favs-preloader").hide();
                     </script>
                     ';
            }

            echo '</table>';
```

Comment: remove the semi-colon from the if($i > 4) and make the $i++ happen in an else after the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code directly it will works...

```
echo '<table id="" class="uiGrid _51mz _1m6c" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">';
    $i = 0;
    while ($r = $get->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {   
        $globals = new \Libraries\Helpers\Views\Globals;
        $i++;
        if ($i == 1)
        {
            echo '<tr class="_51mx">';
        }
        echo '
            <td class="_51m-">
                <a href="/e/a/'.$r->data_id.'">
                    <div class="uiScaledImageContainer _f-u2" style="width:74px;height:74px;">
                        <img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://gstatic.acfee.org/akamaihd/i/'.$globals->data_image_name($r->data_id).'">
                        <div class="_3s6x">
                            <div class="_50f3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
             ';
        if ($i >= 4)
        {
            echo '</tr>';
            $i = 0;
        };
        echo '
             <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#favs-preloader").hide();
             </script>
             ';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you're verifying if the `$i` variable is `== 0` in order to add a row. But you're always increasing it's value at the end, even after you set it to zero in the `if($i > 4)`

Change these lines

```
if ($i > 4)
{
    $i = 0;
    echo '</tr>';
};

$i++;
```

To this:

```
if ($i > 4)
{
    $i = 0;
    echo '</tr>';
}
else
$i++;
```

Comment: Did you get different results? Try adding an = symbol on the if: `$i >= 4`

Comment: I changed $i = 1, instead of how it was $i = 0 and it worked

Comment: Cool! That was because when you say if $i > 4, it's when it's value is 5. And from 0 to 5 there are 6 values. What you did will work :)

Comment: Thanks for ur assistance. New to PHP and hoping to make it a primary language. Enjoy the day

Comment: Thank you, don't forget to pick the accepted answer ;)